# comparar dos tablas para grabar la puntuación más alta

Tags: lua

Estoy intentando comparar las tablas score[1] y highscore[1] para obtener la puntuación más alta y grabarla en highscore.json pero no me funciona. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? 
Gracias

```
local function onCollision_1(event)
if event.phase == "began" then

    local agro = event.object1
    local hit = event.object2
    if agro.type == "ball" and hit.type == "exit" then
    elseif agro.type == "exit" and hit.type == "ball" then

        initialtime.text = initialtime.text + clockText.text
        score = {}
        highscore = {}
        highscore[1] = initialtime.text
        score[1] = initialtime.text
        loadsave.saveTable(score, "score.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)          
        score = loadsave.loadTable("score.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)  

    if  score[1] > highscore[1] then
        loadsave.saveTable(highscore, "highscore.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
        highscore = loadsave.loadTable("highscore.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    else
```

end
            showpoints = function() 
            storyboard.gotoScene("play", "fade", 800) end
            timer.performWithDelay(2000, showpoints)
        end
    end
end

Answer (score 1):

De lo que entiendo necesitas verificar si el puntaje actual es mayor al histórico para luego guardarlo en alguna especie de SDK no indicado, esto podría hacerse de la siguiente forma

```
local high = {1000}
local score = {2000}

local max = math.max -- es más rápido declarar las variables globales como locales
high[1] = max(score[1],high[1])
print(unpack(high)) -- se imprime: 2000
```

Para guardar `high` luego de acuerdo a las funciones o instancias que hayas definido previamente.